# XCode 7 Storyboard UI Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout, width

Ever since updating to XCode7/iOS9 something very strange seems to be happening.  In my storyboard layout, the views are still the fixed 320 x 568.  I was having an issue where a good chunk of the right side of the screen was being cut off when I would run the iPhone 6 simulator.  So I created a new test project with storyboard and 1 view.  I added a sub view, set it's background red, and made it the same size as the parent: 320 wide and set a width constraint of 320 on it.  My expectation is that the red subview will scale to any size iPhone screen width.

[image]

What I get is the following:

[image]

So I logged self.view.frame.size.width and it is saying the width is 375.  In the storyboard, I set the width of the red subview to 375, updated the width constraint to 375 and what do you know...it fills the width of the parent view perfectly as it should.

The problem is, I shouldnt have to do this.  Why would I do my design off the screen?

Is there something Apple is trying to force here that I am not doing?  I never had this issue in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing constraints as far as I can see.
Please add constraints as appropriate.
Recommend you add the Left and Right margins, and Top space + height.

I.e., Click the square when your "red" view is selected, then click the left, right and top sides of the box. Then click the "height" field and then "add constraints"

Comment: Well, this was never enforced before xcode 7.  Maybe it is now?  I know, normally I add at least a leading, top, and trailing constraint, but in particular cases, I want to have several views that start off screen and animate in, so lets say one of them doesnt have a trailing constraint.  The problem is now, it will show up 320 instead of 375 wide.  Or I will just have to do more work now and add more programmatic constraints I suppose.

Comment: It's not "enforced". IT just doesn't know what to do and uses a static size. Trust me and do this. I promise it will work work... or you can send me your code!

Comment: I know it will work, I just never had to set the constraints this explicitly before.  In previous versions of xcode you could do what I just did without any constraints and it would work

Comment: Agreed, but it's silly to argue against Apple, the tides change. Please let me know if it worked for you?